# How can I update in MySQL using the HTML form?

Tags: php, html, webforms

I have created a website (you don't want to see that). Now i want to input students details there. I created a tiny table for testing, only 3 rows - firstname, lastname, age.

I created a simple HTML form and a PHP script, now I can input data and save there easily.
Now the problem is I don't seem to find an easy way to update data.

I have some knowledge in Oracle database, forms and reports. I was thinking to populate HTML forms from MySQL data (similar to Oracle Forms) and update and save. I did not find a way to do that. I searched Google and got some complicated long code, did not understand properly.

If possible, please give me the simplest way (no validation, no security check, etc) to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have a look at the PDO section on the PHP website. It's at php.net/pdo, it's fairly straightforward. You need to make a connection, prepare a statement, and then execute it with variables for the data you want to inject into it. Give it a go?

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide no code of your website, I can only assume that you are using a query to insert data into the database? Should be something like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1,value2,...)";
```

To update, you can use the same type of form, except the query would be:

```
$query = "UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ... WHERE some_column = some_value";
```

You can find more information here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp
If you want more help, show us more code and tell us what the column names are in the database. I can the provide exact variables to put in the query.